# Is it possible to query past events with the Facebook Graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

Until today I managed to retrieve past events on Facebook via FQL. But recently FQL had some changes and now there it became impossible to query past events including my friends attending all in one call.

Does anyone have a clue how to retrieve past event information via the Graph API? /events only returns upcoming events.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I think you can get the same events through the `/events` call. If you go to [the Facebook link for the Graph API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/), you can click on the "Events" link that looks like `Events: https://graph.facebook.com/me/events?access_token=...`. In the returned data, there's a `paging` section with both `previous` and `next` links. You should be able to get past event information through that.

edit: As Jeroen pointed out, you can also use `since` and `until` to filter more, and `limit` to reduce the number of results.

Comment: Thanks, I also found out that adding since=0 or until=time() results in much more events. Adding limit=x could help if the paging isn't for you.

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem when running the query **without** the `start_time > 0` . It seems that facebook enters a `start_time` limit that is not visible, maybe not.
So if you run the query don't forget that. In my case, without `start_time > 0`, it returned 6 events and with it returned 24.
I had to search the internet a few hours before finding this and understanding why.

Answer (score 1):

Works for me.

FQL example

select name from event where eid in ( SELECT eid from event_member WHERE uid = {you page or user id here} and start_time > '2001-11-02T12:35:00+0200')

Since FQL doesn't support ( Select * ), address FQL manual to query more fields https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/